# Mathematica - Reflect/invert unidirect graph edges

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given is a graph with data in mathematica-11. The graph includes undirected edges between nodes and standalone nodes (not connected).

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2<-> 3, 3<-> 1, 4<-> 5, 5<-> 6, 6<-> 2, 2<-> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond", VertexSize -> Small]
```

[image: Graph with edges]

*Question*:

How do I reflect (invert) the edges between the nodes?

Since they are unidirected, by reflecting/inverting I mean that those nodes are supposed to be linked where no edge was before (and the former edges are gone).

Mathematica-11 provides the **[ReverseGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseGraph.html)** function, however this one does only reflect directed edges by their direction. Any ideas?

*Idea*:

Convert the graph into a [AdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html) and inverse it. Then, the inversed matrix could be used to create the reflected/inverted graph.
However, I am stuck with inverting the AdjacencyMatrix since the result will behavior strange:

[image: Inverted AdjacencyMatrix]

So simple the true values are replaced with the term inverse when using `Inverse (AdjacencyMatrix[data]) // MatrixForm`

*Related*:

[This article](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4520/how-to-get-graph-layout-that-reflects-edge-weights/95836#95836) covers how to reflect edge weights, but not the edges itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question so if this isn't the answer tell us why not:

```
opts = {VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexShapeFunction -> "Diamond", VertexSize -> Small}

g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 2, 2 <-> 4}];
```

Then you might like

```
GraphComplement[g1, opts]
```

or, if you want edges from each node to itself

```
AdjacencyGraph[Table[1, {VertexCount[g1]}, {VertexCount[g1]}] - AdjacencyMatrix[g1], opts]
```